# Switch jQuery onClick to keyCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode, keypad

What am I missing in order to translate my jQuery onClick events into keypress events where a user can use a keypad?

The specific example is for a calculator. Using jQuery and the on click/touch events work perfect. However, when I try to introduce keyCodes I am not getting the results I think I should.

Here is my example code;

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var display = "0";
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode === 13){
        alert(keycode + " = ENTER");    
        calcDisplay(total(), true);
    }
});
```

Most of this I picked up from other successful solutions to similar issues. So the way I understand it is; if someone presses *"enter"* on the keyboard, I'd get my alert and then process my answer.

The jQuery version of this that works for me looks like this;

```
$(".button").on("click touch", function(){
    var button = $(this).data("value");
    if(button === "="){
      calcDisplay(total(), true);
    }
```

superNewb to JS here so much love ahead of time if this is something super foolish on my end.

Comment: Your code should work. Here's a plunker with it working https://plnkr.co/edit/mvDnrOEiUPgmUKWBj5OD?p=preview . What does `console.log(keycode);` give you right before `if(keycode === 13)`

Comment: If you log `keycode`, what the value logged?

Comment: listen to `keydown` instead of `keypress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keypress` is meant to be used when characters are being inserted as input. `keydown` is meant to be used to detect *any* key.

[quirksmode has a nice little write-up about the differences](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html).

Instead of `$(document).keypress` use `$(document).keydown`.

---

Additionally, jQuery normalizes `event.which`, so instead of:

```
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
```

you can use

```
var key = e.which;
```

Comment: Magical! All of the operators are working as needed. Also, it appears that I was trying to execute this separately looking for the calcDisplay() function before it was defined. Haven't yet solved the numeric keycodes just yet but we're on the right path. Thank you all for the help.